# How do you stop the Designer generating code for public properties on a User Control?

Tags: c#, winforms

How do you stop the designer from auto generating code that sets the value for public properties on a user control?

Comment: i wonder what is the purpose for designer to monkey with your properties...

Comment: I had problems opening designer because I'd accidentally serialized an object from an older version of a classlib I was using.  Tedious to trace: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272552/visual-studio-2013-designer-trying-to-load-wrong-version-of-project-dll

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use the DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute on the properties that you want to hide from the designer serialization and set the parameter to Hidden.

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public string Name
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Comment: Very useful if base form has public property bound to one control's text property. Editor wants to set the value in inherited form and so messes with localization. Similar to [another problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13145340/395718) on SO.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following attributes to the property in your control:

```
[Browsable(false), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
```

Answer (score -1):

A slight change to Erik's answer I am using VS 2013.

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public new string Name { 
    get; 
    set; 
}
```

Comment: My naming of the property to "Name" was unfortunate. It would've been better to name it something different than that since all controls already have a Name property. That's the reason you have to use the new keyword to hide the base class property. :)

Comment: Yes I've fallen foul of this myself since the answer.

Comment: As mentioned by Erik himself this answer, doesn't add anything to new to the actual question

Comment: No need for a down vote, the new is a requirement. Please read Erik's response correctly.

Comment: @peterincumbria It is only a requirement if the class you are using already has the name property and you are trying to write your own. Therefore this doesn't add anything to the answer as the attribute is the answer not the new keyword. Alternatively I could write my own answer overriding the property using the override keyword instead of new.

Comment: As far I I know, the `Name` property of user controls is a `public string`, not `virtual`, therefor you cannot `override` the property; you need to use the `New` keyword.  The title clearly states that we are talking about a User Control.