# What is the equivalent of [DesignerSerializationVisibility] or [Browsable] in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

In traditional winforms development I have become accustomed to the [[DesignerSerializationVisibility]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696/how-do-you-stop-the-designer-generating-code-for-public-properties-on-a-user-cont) attribute to prevent the designer trying to serialize properties that shouldn't be serialized at design time.

This doesn't seem to exist in silverlight. What is the equivalent way to hide a property from the designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still the BrowseableAttribute, but you'll need to apply it via Design time Metadata.

Read more about it in my blog post @ [Silverlight Design time Extensibility](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/justinangel/archive/2009/07/28/132766.aspx)
And Ning Zhang's blog @ http://www.ningzhang.org/

My original design time article specifically mentions BrowsableAttribute.

As part of the Silverlight Toolkit we shipped source code for Silverlight Toolkit & SDK Design time metadata which you can use as a sample.