# Object of type 'Data.TimeLineChartedDay[]' cannot be converted to type 'Data.TimeLineChartedDay[]'?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm getting the following Designer Error in VS2008 :

```
 Object of type 'Data.TimeLineChartedDay[]' cannot be 
 converted to type 'Data.TimeLineChartedDay[]'.
```

???

```
public class TimeLineDisplay     
{
    private List<TimeLineChartedDay> chartedDays = new List<TimeLineChartedDay>();

    public List<TimeLineChartedDay> ChartedDays         
    {
        get { return chartedDays; }
        set { chartedDays = value;  }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class TimeLineChartedDay
{
    private DateTime date;
    private int chartValue;

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return date; }
        set { date = value; }
    }

    public int ChartValue
    {
        get { return chartValue; }
        set { chartValue = value; }
    }

    public TimeLineChartedDay()
    { 

    }
}
```

VS STACK :

```
    at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
    at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.InternalSetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean doVisibilityCheck, Boolean doCheckConsistency)
    at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.InternalSetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean doVisibilityCheck)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.SerializationSetValue(MemberInfo fi, Object target, Object value)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteObject(ObjectHolder holder, Boolean bObjectFullyComplete)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoNewlyRegisteredObjectFixups(ObjectHolder holder)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.RegisterObject(Object obj, Int64 objectID, SerializationInfo info, Int64 idOfContainingObj, MemberInfo member, Int32[] arrayIndex)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.RegisterObject(Object obj, ParseRecord pr, ParseRecord objectPr, Boolean bIsString)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ParseObjectEnd(ParseRecord pr)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Parse(ParseRecord pr)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
    at System.Resources.ResXDataNode.GenerateObjectFromDataNodeInfo(DataNodeInfo dataNodeInfo, ITypeResolutionService typeResolver)
    at System.Resources.ResXDataNode.GetValue(ITypeResolutionService typeResolver)
    at System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.ParseDataNode(XmlTextReader reader, Boolean isMetaData)
    at System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.ParseXml(XmlTextReader reader)
```

Previous to this error the following occured :
I added a self written control. VS crashed with the following message: "Class TimeLineChartedDay is not marked as serializable". I found this strange because it was written on another machine, which didn't complain about the 'Serializable' attribute. I added the attribute to the class, and stumbled on the preivous mentioned error.

Comment: Why is your class in a ResX file?

Comment: ??? my class isn't in a resX file .. ??, just a standard .cs file ..

Comment: But it's being serialized into a .ResX.  Why?

Comment: If I understand correctly, upon adding the TimeLineDisplay control to a form, the VS editor wrote a default initialisation value for 'ChartedDays'.  These values were then saved in a resx file by VS ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your control is trying to serialize the class instance when it probably shouldn't.

You should probably add `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]` to the property that exposes the `TimeLineDisplay`.

For more specific advice, please show us your control.

Comment: I added the attribute, but to no avail ... I'm now getting this designer error:

Comment: [A]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Data.TimeLineChartedDay] cannot be cast to [B]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Data.TimeLineChartedDay]. Type A originates from 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Type B originates from 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.

Comment: Rebuild your project and restart Visual Studio.  You may also need to manually edit the designer.cs and/or the .ResX to remove the list.

Comment: That did it. I had to remove the reference in the designer file. Thanks a million!!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with a custom control.
Though adding the control via designer failed with the message "Class is not marked as serializable", it added a variable to the Designer.cs file and an entry the .resx file.

I had to remove those entries by hand and everything worked well. For the resx file I did right click -> Open with -> Source Editor and searched for entries containing the class name and removed them.

Comment: This. Life-saver! What a b*****d of a error that was!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with a Form containing a custom control. The custom control had a public property for a custom class X. (Class X was a simple DTO, serializable, and contained a default constructor.) The form designer displayed an error like:

`"Object of type “X” cannot be converted to object of type “X”"`

If you double click the forms .resx file, the resx designer will show all of the resources for the form. (note: in the upper left of the designer, there is a drop down to filter by resource type). The offending object appears as a line item (in my case, it was liste under type "other")  Delete the line item and save all.