# How to show a list of filenames in a PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, propertygrid

I am using a PropertyGrid control in a C# WinForms application. Various objects in my application have images associated with them, and for these I use a class called ImageType, which contains a caption and a path for the image.

```
public class ImageType
{
    public ImageType() { }

    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

I use the `OpenFilenameEditor` to give the image a browse button in the PropertyGrid.

This is all fine.

However, one of my object types (so far) requires multiple images. I implemented this as a list i.e. `List<ImageType>`.

```
public class Foo {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";
        public List<ImageType> Images { get; set; }
}
```

This worked but it didn't display in a particularly useful way in the PropertyGrid. There are two things I want to happen:

1) Each image in the list should be displayed in its own row in the PropertyGrid, and

2) Each image in the list should have its own browse button in the PropertyGrid.

I have been using the method described in [this example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4448/Customized-display-of-collection-data-in-a-Propert) but (a) I haven't yet got the browse buttons working, (b) it requires a lot of code, and (c) I'm not sure whether this level of complexity is necessary.

To implement this method I changed my list of `ImageType` to a custom collection called `ImageCollection`, inheriting from `CollectionBase` and `ICustomTypeDescriptor`. I would rather stick with a list if possible, though, for simplicity.

Is the approach taken in the above project the best way to go here, or is there a simpler way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: `DataGridView` control would be the right tool to display collection of objects.

Comment: That would seem a clunky solution since it would separate those properties from the rest (i.e. it would require a second control).

Comment: If you notice how properties editor works in Visual Studio, for complex properties it opens new form.

Comment: Check out [How do I make a property of a custom control open a file dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61681331/10216583). More links in there.