# How to add a method link at Designer Property Editor?

Tags: c#, designer

I have made a user control and I have a Method that takes as input a file.
I wonder if there is a way to expose the method at the designer.

For now I have made a Property which I expose to the designer. But I would want it to be a method instead. Or at least a property without the {get} part.
Example:

```
public class a : control {


    [EditorAttribute(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Design.FileNameEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor)),
     Category("Behavior"), Description("...")]
    public void Load(string FileName) {
        ...
    }

    [EditorAttribute(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Design.FileNameEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor)),
     Category("Behavior"), Description("...")]
    public string LoadFile
    {
        {get;}
        set {Load(value);}
    }
}
```

The property LoadFile will appear normally in the property editor.
The method Load will not...
If I remove the {get;} the property will not appear in the property editor.

Desired behavior:

I would like that the Property editor would have a link with Load like you see in some controls like DataGridView with edit/add columns..., etc...
Is that possible? And how?

Clearly when the user clicks Load I want the FileNameEditor and the designer to produce the line:
this.a1.Load(".....");

Thank you

Comment: Build your own FileNameEditor UITypeEditor. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61681331/7444103) (different language, but same thing. You can find more examples like this). Of course, you need a Property. In the custom editor, use whatever you need.

Comment: Ty for answering but it is not an issue of a custom UITypeEditor.
Some controls add a link to call their methods.
How do the do that?

Comment: This happens in another context. My comment is related to the code you posted. What a Control is doing with the Property value it gets from the Property grid is not related to the Property grid editor, not directly. If you want to add a LinkLabel (or assign a value to it) to a UserControl / Custom Control, this happens internally, after the Property grid has returned a value. Your Property just exposes the standard public getter and setter.

Comment: I repeat: I want the Designer's Property Editor to get a link to edit the initial value of my method!
If I do it as a Property it works fine for 1 value. Normally, it should be a method.
The Property Editor somehow can do what I want, the question is how?
For you to understand add a DataGridView to a form, go to the Property Editor and click the add columns link. This will open the UITypeEditor (in my case the FileNameEditor) and produce a result like columns.add(EDITOR OUTPUT).

Comment: That's a specialized collection editor, not a `FileNameEditor`. Completely different functionality. The internal logic doesn't change, though. You access that editor through a Property. The editor deals with the Collection objects it refers to. You need to build a custom Form to handle the creation of objects and a PropertyGrid Control to allow editing the Properties of the selected object.

Comment: If the collection of objects is simple, you can try to use the standard (default) CollectionEditor and see whether it's enough for what you're planning to do with your objects.