# How to deserialize a MemoryStream'ed object from one assembly in another assembly c#

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, autocad-plugin

I'm working or re-writting an AutoCAD plugin that is .NET C#.

I have a List of type IZone, which is an interface I've written for the old plugin.

```
public interface IZone
    {
        string zoneNum { get; set; }
        string handle { get; set; }
        int color { get; set; }
        int colorIndex { get; }

        string thermostat { get; set; }

        void UpdateColor();
        bool IsPtInZone(Point3d insPt);
        
    }
```

This interfaces gets implemented by Zone, and these zone objects are created, added to a list, and then passed to be serialized(in order to be stored in AutoCAD as an Xrecord, not as important)

This is what does the serialization, which is an outside assembly from the old plugin, and which our old plugin is dependent on this outside assembly.

```
public static ResultBuffer SerializeXrecordData(object objectToSerialize)
        {
            ResultBuffer buffer;
            MemoryStream serializationStream = new MemoryStream();
            try
            {
                new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(serializationStream, objectToSerialize);
                byte[][] bufferArray = ChunkStream(serializationStream);
                if (bufferArray.Length <= 0)
                {
                    buffer = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    List<TypedValue> list = new List<TypedValue> {
                        new TypedValue(1, objectToSerialize.GetType().FullName)
                    };
                    int index = 0;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (index >= bufferArray.Length)
                        {
                            buffer = new ResultBuffer(list.ToArray());
                            break;
                        }
                        list.Add(new TypedValue(310, bufferArray[index]));
                        index++;
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (!ReferenceEquals(serializationStream, null))
                {
                    serializationStream.Dispose();
                }
            }
            return buffer;
        }
```

In trying to recreate the deserialization code, I've run into an error where I get an error

`{"Object of type 'Company.Interfaces.IZone[]' cannot be converted to type 'Company.Interfaces.IZone[]'."}`

I have copied the C# file for the interface completely from the old plugin into the new plugin, just for this conversion as it is important for backwards compatibility.

This is what I am using to try and deserialize

```
public static object DeSerializeXrecordData(ResultBuffer xrecordData)
        {
            object obj2;
            bool flag = xrecordData != null;
            if (!flag)
            {
                obj2 = null;
            }
            else
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter {
                    Binder = new DomainBinder()
                };
                MemoryStream serializationStream = new MemoryStream();
                try
                {
                    TypedValue[] valueArray = xrecordData.AsArray();
                    int index = 1;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        flag = index < valueArray.Length;
                        if (!flag)
                        {
                            serializationStream.Position = 0L;
                            obj2 = formatter.Deserialize(serializationStream);
                            break;
                        }
                        if (valueArray[index].TypeCode == 310)
                        {
                            byte[] buffer = (byte[]) valueArray[index].Value;
                            serializationStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        }
                        index++;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (!ReferenceEquals(serializationStream, null))
                    {
                        serializationStream.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            return obj2;
        }
```

```
public class DomainBinder : SerializationBinder
        {
            public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
            {
                string str = assemblyName.Split(new char[] { ',' })[0];
                Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
                int index = 0;
                while (true)
                {
                    Type type;
                    if (index >= assemblies.Length)
                    {
                        type = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        char[] separator = new char[] { ',' };
                        if (str != assemblies[index].FullName.Split(separator)[0])
                        {
                            index++;
                            continue;
                        }
                        type = assemblies[index].GetType(typeName);
                    }
                    return type;
                }
            }
        }
```

Where I've added this to the `DomainBinder` as an attempt that I saw online

```
string str = assemblyName.Split(new char[] { ',' })[0];

            Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

            if (str.Equals("CompanyNamePlugin"))
            {
                return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(typeName);
            }
```

I'm wondering if since the List in the old plugin was a list of type `List<IZone>` which was filled with instances of `Zone` that implemented `IZone`, but `Zone` is not present in this new assembly, if that might be part of the problem?

Comment: I've seen `Object of type TypeA cannot be  converted to TypeA` when referencing different versions of the assembly they are defined in. Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452001/object-of-type-data-timelinechartedday-cannot-be-converted-to-type-data-tim

Comment: After looking at that link @EricJ. I dont think it really applies to the situation here. It seemed that issue was fixed by changing something during the serialization process. The serialization has already been done in my case, and I can't change it now.