# Object of type 'X' cannot be converted to type 'Y'

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

I've seen such question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115593/object-of-type-x-cannot-be-converted-to-object-of-type-x) but I didn't find the answer.

I have two project:

- WinForms library

  - **BaseUserComponent** (abstract class inherited from *System.ComponentModel.Component*
  - **MyControl** (Has property named *Component* of **BaseUserComponent** type)
- WinForms application

  - **UserComponent** (implementation of **BaseUserComponent**)
  - **Form** (which contains **UserComponent** and **MyControl**)

The trouble is when designer trying to assign the *Component* property of *MyControl* to instance of *UserComponent*. When I open designer first time all work correctly but after any change in form designer shows error `'Object of type 'UserComponent' cannot be converted to type 'BaseUserComponent'`. But `UserComponent` is inherited from `BaseUserComponent`, so it should work normally.

Exception:

```
at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object component, Object value)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object component, Object value)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializePropertyAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeAssignStatement statement, CodePropertyReferenceExpression propertyReferenceEx, Boolean reportError)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeAssignStatement statement)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)
```

I've tried to rebuild whole solution, project many times and it has no effect.

Comment: Could it be a version problem?  Look closely at the error message: is the BaseUserComponent that you derive from the same as the conversion is to?  You can get into this situation if the two binaries refer to different versions of the same library.

Comment: I think no if you mean AssemblyVersion attribute. I never change version of library. If problem was in versioning of library rebuilding of solution would be helped, but it wouldn't. I've found one detail yet, the exception shows when I just build the project without any changes after project loading.