# Value of type ... cannot be converted to

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I keep receiving the following error whenever I try to run my code. Are there any suggestions on what may be causing me to not be able to convert? It seems as though both types are the same, so I'm a little confused on this one.

```
Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of CVE)' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of CVE)'
```

Error is occurring here:

```
Dim cveList As List(Of CVE)
cveList = CVERepository.GetInstance.ReadAllCVEs
```

Here's the CVERepository class:

```
Public Class CVERepository

Private Sub New()

End Sub

Public Shared ReadOnly Property GetInstance As CVERepository
    Get
        Static Instance As CVERepository = New CVERepository
        Return Instance
    End Get
End Property

Public Function ReadAllCVEs() As List(Of CVE)
    Dim objAdapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dtCVE As New DataTable()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim dvCVE As DataView

    strConn = ConnectStringBuild()
    strSQL = "Select * From CVE"

    objAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, strConn)
    objAdapter.Fill(dtCVE)
    dvCVE = dtCVE.DefaultView
    Dim cveList As New List(Of CVE)

    'Put it into an object list to make it more managable.
    For index = 0 To dvCVE.Count - 1
        Dim cve As New CVE
        cve.ID = dvCVE(index)("CVEID")
        cve.PublishedDate = dvCVE(index)("PublishedDate")
        cve.Availability = dvCVE(index)("Availability")
        cve.CVSSScore = dvCVE(index)("CVSSScore")
        cve.Confidentiality = dvCVE(index)("Confidentiality")
        cve.Integrity = dvCVE(index)("Integrity")
        cve.Summary = dvCVE(index)("Summary")
        cveList.Add(cve)
    Next

    Return cveList

End Function

Public Shared Function ConnectStringBuild() As String
    'Grabbing connection string from web.config
    Return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CVEConnectionString").ConnectionString
End Function

End Class
```

Any suggestion on the error?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115593/object-of-type-x-cannot-be-converted-to-object-of-type-x ?

Comment: Andrew - You were right. I'm working with ASP.net and had created a CVE.aspx page which automatically created a CVE object. Therefore the CVE class I had created earlier created a conflict.

Answer (score 1):

just a little change

```
Dim cveList As List(Of CVE)
cveList.AddRange(CVERepository.GetInstance.ReadAllCVEs)
```