# Weird exception converting from a type to the same type

Tags: c#, user-interface, compiler-errors, type-conversion

I'm working on an old, and not well-written GUI. The designer can't even render one of the controls and shows the following error:

> Object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[A.B.C.SettingsDomain.ShiftSetUpEntry]'
>   cannot be converted to type  'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[A.B.C.SettingsDomain.ShiftSetUpEntry]'.

This is the literal, verbatim copy of the text message (except *A.B.C*, which contains the company's name and which it'd be unwise to disclose here).

Now, correct me if I'm wrong but I was under the impression that converting from a type to the same type shouldn't be a cause of any errors. Apparently, .NET disagrees with me and I'm buffed by that fact. This is a bit of what the duck moment (typo intended).

I can (and probably will have to) go in to the autogenerated code setting up the stupid GUI and edit by hand "*from the kitchen*" but still, what's up with that message?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115593/object-of-type-x-cannot-be-converted-to-object-of-type-x

Comment: Provide a reproducible example of the problem.

Comment: I have only ever seen that when you have references pointing to different versions of the same assembly, so essentially they are different types with the same name in the same namespace.

Comment: @Servy I'd love to. Sadly, I don't think it's possible given the size of the projects and the quality of all the code I'm dealing with. There's been a lot of cooks in that soup before me... This is one of those cases where I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @BenRobinson Shouldn't that be remedied by rebuilding a few times? I've done that (and tried all the other tricks in the post suggested in the earlier comments) but to no avail...

Comment: Did you also try cleaning the solution? (sorry if this sounds obvious I overlooked it once, I was not amused when I figured it out after hours of debugging)

Comment: @KonradViltersten: rebuilding the project doesn't change what's referenced, nor the code that uses those references. You need to resolve the conflict. As for posting a reproducible example, Servy's not suggesting you post the actual code. To post a _good_ question (here or anywhere else), you need to do some work yourself to _create_ a simple, reproducible example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @PeterDuniho I understand what Servy means. If I had a simple example, I'd post it. And I haven't been able to recreate the issue on small, partial samples from the code. It's an old, dusty project, written badly as a sin and I'm generally unclear on how it's assembled. However, I asked like this because I was quite convinced that such a weird and general error should be recognized from other situations. If you haven't seen it before, you won't probably be able to help me here. In fact, it seems that restarting VS three times (yes, really) did the trick.   :(

Comment: @KonradViltersten: _"If I had a simple example, I'd post it."_ The point is that a good question always involves _creating_ a simple example for the purpose of posting the question. As for this: _"If you haven't seen it before, you won't probably be able to help me"_ I run into problems I've never seen before every day, both in my own coding and in helping others. And yet, I often am able to arrive at a solution. Not having seen a problem before is not a barrier to solving it, if you have good problem-solving skills.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I believe you're missing my point. I **can't** create a simple example showing the problem. I'm not sure why, despite having spent a couple of hours trying to do that (before I ask here, I always try to solve stuff myself because it's annoying to get dupe notifications, if not for other reasons). I believe you could solve the problem **if you were here**. But you're not. That's why you expect a simple example, right? Since I can't create one, you won't be able to help me. Unless you've seen that error before (eliminating the need to reproduction in a simple way).

Comment: @PeterDuniho Also, please note that the issue got resolved. In a very weird way (which makes me suspect that the **actual** remedy was something else, which I'm unaware of). If you know how to reproduce such weirdness, you're welcome to educate me. My guess is that no one can, since the description is vague at best. Unless someone's seen that before...