# C#, editing in UserControl doesn't inherit graphics

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a custom control, MyControl, that inherits from UserControl.

If i change MyControl graphic proprerties(like ForeColor, backgroundImage, etc) i aspect this will be applied to all my instances of MyControl, but is not.

Why?

**EDIT**

I think the problem is that image are stored inside resx file of Control that contains MyControl (example a Form).
When this line is called, the old image is applied.

```
resources.ApplyResources(this.myControl1, "myControl1");
```

So when i make changes in MyControl designer class, this are not applied to myControl1 instance.
Unfortunately this line was autogenerated in designer of Form.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us some code? specially, the part where you change the graphic properties.

Comment: I change MyControl BackGround image in design mode. I have an instance of MyControl inside a Form, but here the backgroundimage remaing the same, doesn't change. I noticed that the background image is stored inside resx file of MyForm, how can i refresh this file in all Form where i have used MyControl?

Comment: do you first add your control and then change its backgroundimage or is it changed in a separate project in design mode of the control?

Comment: just so we are clear. When you change the background property on the form, the control in that form changes but not the ones in other forms. am I getting this right? or does none of theme change?

Comment: The second one, i have already placed all MyControls, but now i want change backgroundimage, so i tryed to change backgroundimage from MyControl(in separate project), but this change does not be applied...

Comment: Have you built the project for the control?

Comment: Yes i always rebuild my controls lib project

Comment: What happens if you remove the control from the form and then put it back, after you made your changes?

Comment: I see the new backgroundimage, but i don't want to remove and reput all... MyControl is a sort of container and is used in every form of my project

Comment: Add some info in my question.

Comment: Check the code that is generated in the form.designer.cs. It probably is setting each property to the value that were used when your original placed the control on the form.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your settings (eg. change background image and stuff) in a constructor of MyControl or in the designer of the control, not Form.

Comment: No this does not work. And now i does'nt make change in Form, but in designer of MyControl class.

Answer (score 0):

Well of course it doesn't.
When you add the control to a form, it grabs the properties and adds code in form.designer.cs, setting them. Change them in the form designer, those chamges get persisted in .designer.cs

If you then change the control itself, to pick up those changes you'd have to remove and add it again.

The only way round that is for the properties not to be configurable in the designer.

Comment: Thank you, "The only way round that is for the properties not to be configurable in the designer", so how can i achieve this now?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696/how-do-you-stop-the-designer-generating-code-for-public-properties-on-a-user-con

Comment: Looks like @sgmoore dug that out for you. Think about the consequences though, you'll be saying you never want to set that property at design time.

Comment: ok, this is not a solution for me... the only thing now works is to set my properties on Load event...