# Localization in Visual Studio 2008: What's my mistake?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, localization

I'm trying to create a localized version of a Windows Form in Visual Studio 2008.

Following various walkthrought, I set the form property Localizable to TRUE, and set the form language to French.

I then edit the French version. Visual Studio shows a .fr.resx file as well as the .resx in the workspace.

However, if I switch back to the (Default) version, all the English strings in the default version have now been replaced by the French version.

Obviously I'm missing something very obvious: can anyone suggest what it is?

Comment: I've had similar problem description, and solution for me was to add [one attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29720/395718) to a property that editor was constantly messing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean in the forms designer itself, the form is still appearing in French? If you look at the ".resx" files directly, are the strings in the correct language. If so then have you tried closing and re-loading the form, or cleaning the project, or clearing and then resetting the "Localizable" property, or re-starting Visual Studio altogether. I've seen strange language issues like this many times (I'm the developer of a localization program for Visual Studio), but the above solutions normally correct the problem. The designer has its problems sometimes (among other things).

Comment: It looks like it was an intermittent VS2008 bug - after restarting it seems to be working according to specification. Phew!

Comment: Just as I thought. Glad things are working again.