# Designer view error: Could not load file or assembly - wrong assembly version

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I haven't been able to find this particular variety of this error anywhere.

*Designer* view fails with the error below. The failing assembly, `ZedGraph`, is actually version `4.3.8.12` (newly changed), not `4.3.8.11`. I have cleaned, rebuilt and emptied `obj` and `bin` folder manually. Doing a text search on `"4.3.8.11"`. I cannot find it anywhere in my solution, including the project file or solution file. Debugging and deploying works fine.

I have a `UserControl` of my own where the `ZedGraph` component is embedded.
It also uses `DevExpress` components.

Thanks in advance,
Markus

```
Could not load file or assembly 'ZedGraph, Version=4.3.8.11,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified. 

at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName,
String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
suppressSecurityChecks) at
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
suppressSecurityChecks) at
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
suppressSecurityChecks) at
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) at
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
forIntrospection) at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
assemblyString) at
System.UnitySerializationHolder.GetRealObject(StreamingContext
context) at
    System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.ResolveObjectReference(ObjectHolder
holder) at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups() at
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler
handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) at
    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) at
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
serializationStream) at
System.Resources.ResXDataNode.GenerateObjectFromDataNodeInfo(DataNodeInfo
dataNodeInfo, ITypeResolutionService typeResolver) at
System.Resources.ResXDataNode.GetValue(ITypeResolutionService
typeResolver) at
System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.ParseDataNode(XmlTextReader
reader, Boolean isMetaData) at
System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.ParseXml(XmlTextReader reader)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

Solution found here: https://davidhogue.com/blog/2006/10/how-to-keep-the-visual-studio-designer-out-of-your-controls-properties/.

Discussed here: [Visual Studio 2013 designer trying to load wrong version of project DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272552/visual-studio-2013-designer-trying-to-load-wrong-version-of-project-dll).

Comment: Link rot for the first link. :-(