# Object of type 'X[]' cannot be converted to type 'X[]'

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-forms-designer

I have a control with a property like this:

```
public BindingList<I> X { get; private set; } = new SortableBindingList<I>();
```

Where I is an interface. It builds fine, runs fine, but when I add this control to a form (doesn't matter if the form is in the same assembly or not), and then try to open that form in visual studio (2017), the form is not shown and the following error message comes up:

> Object of type 'I[]' cannot be converted to type 'I[]'.

With a call stack of:

> at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder,
>   CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast) at
>   System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo
>   culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr) at
>   System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.UnsafeSetValue(Object obj, Object value,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.SerializationSetValue(MemberInfo
>   fi, Object target, Object value) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteObject(ObjectHolder
>   holder, Boolean bObjectFullyComplete) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoNewlyRegisteredObjectFixups(ObjectHolder
>   holder) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.RegisterObject(Object obj,
>   Int64 objectID, SerializationInfo info, Int64 idOfContainingObj,
>   MemberInfo member, Int32[] arrayIndex) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.RegisterObject(Object
>   obj, ParseRecord pr, ParseRecord objectPr, Boolean bIsString) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ParseObjectEnd(ParseRecord
>   pr) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Parse(ParseRecord
>   pr) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run() at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler
>   handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream) at
>   System.Resources.ResXDataNode.GenerateObjectFromDataNodeInfo(DataNodeInfo
>   dataNodeInfo, ITypeResolutionService typeResolver) at
>   System.Resources.ResXDataNode.GetValue(ITypeResolutionService
>   typeResolver) at
>   System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.ParseDataNode(XmlTextReader
>   reader, Boolean isMetaData) at
>   System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.ParseXml(XmlTextReader reader)

I tried adding

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
```

or

```
[Browsable(false), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
```

as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/29720/68936 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/29717/68936, respectively;

I have also tried replacing the getter-setter with

```
private BindingList<I> myX = new SortableBindingList<I>();
public BindingList<I> myX { get { return myX; } }
```

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/16657926/68936

To no avail. I've tried closing all open documents, closing the solution, restarting visual studio, rebuilding both assemblies, nothing seems to resolve this.

Comment: I had this same error involving IIS where X contained ValueTuple. It was a .NET 4.6 project running under .NET 4.7 at runtime. The IIS process loaded ValueTuple from mscorlib (4.7), even though at compile time it references ValueTuple in a DLL (DLL file version 4.6.26515.6). The IIS project directly references a .NET 4.6 exe file, which it also spawns as an external process. When this exe is spawned, it uses the correct ValueTuple 4.6 DLL but it cannot deserialize data sent from the IIS process which used the mscorlib version of ValueTuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work with

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public BindingList<I> myX { get; private set; } = new SortableBindingList<I>();
```

AND by editing the **.resx file of the containing form** (not the control's) and removing an xml element that looks like this:

```
  <data name="controlName.X" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64">
    <value>
        AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAJsBSW50ZXJmYWNlc0ludmVzdG1lbnRzLCBWZXJzaW9uPTEuMC4w
        LjAsIEN1bHR1cmU9bmV1dHJhbCwgUHVibGljS2V5VG9rZW49bnVsbF1dLCBtc2NvcmxpYiwgVmVyc2lv
        bj00LjAuMC4wLCBDdWx0dXJlPW5ldXRyYWwsIFB1YmxpY0tleVRva2VuPWI3N2E1YzU2MTkzNGUwODkM
        AwAAAExJbnRlcmZhY2VzSW52ZXN0bWVudHMsIFZlcnNpb249MS4wLjAuMCwgQ3VsdHVyZT1uZXV0cmFs
        LCBQdWJsaWNLZXlUb2tlbj1udWxsBQEAAABOU3lzdGVtLkNvbGxlY3Rpb25zLkdlbmVyaWMuTGlzdGAx
        W1tLYW1hVHJlbmRhLkludGVyZmFjZXMuSW52ZXN0bWVudHMuSVBvc2l0aW9uAwAAAAZfaXRlbXMFX3Np
        emUIX3ZlcnNpb24EAAAtS2FtYVRyZW5kYS5JbnRlcmZhY2VzLkludmVzdG1lbnRzLklQb3NpdGlvbltd
        AwAAAAgIAgAAAAkEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHBAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAQrS2FtYVRyZW5kYS5JbnRlcmZhY2Vz
        LkludmVzdG1lbnRzLklQb3NpdGlvbgMAAAAL
</value>
  </data>
```

It seems like just adding DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden is not enough to remove that existing data node from an existing .resx file.